# Search function using CodeIgniter and php

Tags: php, codeigniter

My function in `home` controller

```
public function search(){
    $search = $this->input->post('search');
    $data['users'] =  $this->users_model->search($search);
    $this->load-view('index');
}
```

My function in `users_model` model

```
public function search($search){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->like('username', 'fname','lname', 'mname', $search);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

My function in `view` profile1

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" style="height: 34px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

it has no method because I do not know how to execute it properly.

Call to a member function `search()` on a non-object

Comment: The error is coming from your controller, correct? You have to post the part of the controller where you call the search() function because that's where your problem is

Comment: public function search(){
    $search = $this->input->post('search');
    $data['users'] =  $this->users_model->search($search);
    $this->load-view('index');
  }
this is my function in controller sir sorry im just a newbie here

Comment: You already posted that above. Post the rest of the controller.

Comment: My main problem sir is I do not know where to place my function in view.

Comment: <form action="search" method="">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
this is my view where i should i put my function

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Home::$users_model

Filename: controllers/home.php

Line Number: 156

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp\www\efg\application\controllers\home.php
Line: 156
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\wamp\www\efg\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Please take a look at how to read php error messages, how to follow the stack trace... how to use var_dump() to troubleshoot through your codeand find the problem. PHP errors are not that hard to debug (usually)

Comment: Okay sir I will. Thanks to your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this complete search system

in search form

   <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/search" method="post"> 
        <div class="input-group"> 
        <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="submit" value="search" name="save"/>
        </div>
        </form>
```

view data

```
     <table>
      <tr>
          <td>User Name</td>
          <td>First Name</td>
          <td>Last Name</td>
          <td>Middle Name</td>
      </tr>
<?php foreach($users as $search_show):?>
      <tr>
          <td><?php echo $search_show->username?></td>
          <td><?php echo $search_show->fname?></td>
          <td><?php echo $search_show->lname?></td>
          <td><?php echo $search_show->mname?></td>
      </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>

 </table>
```

in controller

```
    public function search()
{
    $this->load->model('users_model');
    $search = $this->input->post('search');
    $data['users'] =  $this->users_model->search($search);
    $this->load-view('index',$data);
}
```

in model

```
    public function search($search)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->like('username',$search);
    $this->db->or_like('fname',$search);
    $this->db->or_like('lname',$search);
    $this->db->or_like('mname',$search);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! I will try this

Comment: Should I post my View where I am trying to put it?

Comment: Thanks sir A LOT! It's not yet working but thank you to all your responses.

Comment: The same error occurs and I am trying to figure it out. Thanks sir!

Comment: i am updating the complete ans check it@RobertCapistrano

Comment: THANKS SIR!! HOW TO COMMEND YOU? I am just new here.

Comment: ITS NOW WORKING SIR! THANKS.

Comment: 1 more thing sir. This search is actually searching for a specific user in my database, I want to view that user's profile. Is it possible?

Comment: at first you can try more and more, then anyone can give you solution.

Comment: Sir where should I put the view data you just said?

Comment: Okay sir I will try it. Thanks :)

Comment: The "view data" that you're suggesting destroyed my UI design. Maybe bcoz i do not know where to place it properly?

Comment: change it as your requirment

Comment: Okay sir! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `search()` on an undefined property `$this->users_model` which means you have not loaded your model.

You can either load it manually before you need to call it (easy on resources) by writing:

```
$this->load->model('users_model');
```

Or by auto-loading it in the CodeIgniter config (heavy-ish on resources depending on the model).

Comment: I am actually using users_model. The main problem is I can't call the function search.

Comment: Right, is user_model extending CI_Model? Is your user_model all lower-case? Do you have an upper-case letter in a). the file name or b). In the class name?

Comment: Yes it extended the CI_Model. Only the first letter of the class name is on upper case.

Comment: Okay, try adding $this->load->model('Users_model'); with a capital U

Comment: And don't forget to call $this->User_model and not $this->user_model!